# Magmi images excluded

Tags: import, magmi

I have looked through this site for the answer, it seems i can find similar parts but not the exact answer.

we are using Magmi and the products are uploading fine, but the images have the exclude radio button checked. also the image label is blank. this is a configurable product and once i uncheck the radio button the product shows up fine and the configurations are correct.

thank you in advance
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party extension.

Comment: This i don't think is off topic, this is magento related. why guys like you can't answer but comment saying it is off topic. as far as there is not separate forum for this plug in it is still Magento related.

Answer (score 2):

By default the base image will be excluded unless you prefix its path with a `+` sign:

```
        image
+http://foo.com/images
```

You can also try including labels within the `media_gallery` column by separating the label & path with `::`

```
                         media_gallery
http://foo.com/image.png::front view, http://foo.com/image.jpg::back view
```

For more details, see: <strike>http://www.blinkdata.com/magmi-image-attributes-processor/</strike>

Comment: Also -- if you're editing the data in excel you'll have to escape the `+` with a single quote: `'+`